# Scan the current page to get the inner html in java

Tags: javascript, java, html, encryption

I need to encrypt a value contained in an html div when a user clicks on a button.

In order to do this, I'm calling my custom encryption function from a java plugin inside the javascript onClick() code. The java plugin is a server-side package containing classes of functions that can be called inside the client-side code.

The problem is than my custom function can only take a hardcoded string as parameter :

- `${fn:myCustomFunc("myString")}` encrypts the string myString
- `${fn:myCustomFunc(myStringVariable)}` doesn't encrypt the string contained inside myStringVariable.

Is there a way, inside my java function, to scan the **current page** to get the inner html of the element I need ?

Comment: java or Javascript..?

Comment: @SatejS my encryption function is java. the script in wich I call this function is javascript.

Comment: What is your understanding of a *"java plugin"*? Are you talking about a Java applet or about server-side code? If it's the latter, there are obviously requests going over the wire (see: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/1816580)). Since you haven't shared what the *"java plugin"* is doing, this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

On button click, you can send your string variable to a java class from HTML page and in that java class you can perform encryption.

Comment: The only way I know to do so is to use jsp, and unfortunately I can't in my actual context. 
I can only use javascript, html, and java. The java functions are contained in a plugin deployed on the server, and can be called in the html or javascript.

Comment: You can invoke java methods on jsp page as well.